# Cookie not setting when redirecting between same proxy URLs

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, http-redirect, apigee, jsessionid

I have a scenario where we are using Okta for authentication and trying to use Apigee proxy in between to route our requests.

What is happening:

1. We start the front-end site
2. Request hits the back-end API (`/login`) to start the authentication
3. Okta does the authentication and sends the request back to API (e.g. `/saml/sso`)
4. API then fetches the information from Okta's response and redirects to another endpoint (e.g. `/auth/success`) in the same API
5. This new endpoint (`/auth/success`) is supposed to send the request back to front-end site, but instead it actually sends the request back to Okta for verification.

The issue I am running into because of this is an endless loop between my API and Okta. I tried the tracing at Apigee and I see that when the redirection is happening to `/auth/success` from `/saml/sso` there is a `Set-Cookie` parameter response header and in that there is a `JSESSIONID` value, but when the redirection is happening to `/auth/success` endpoint, I don't see this `JSESSIONID` value in the cookie in request header and that is the reason I believe why it's going back to Okta.

What can I do for this issue? I am new to this Apigee platform and still trying to figure things out.

**Trace Session in Apigee**

**redirecting to** `/auth/success` with `Set-Cookie` with the `JSessionID` in response header:

[image]

**Next request going to** `/auth/success` with cookie, but no `JSessionID` in it:

[image]

Comment: It would be difficult to guess without sample code. But it appears the 2nd call is treated as a new request, try and copy the cookie headers from the target response using an assign message policy before redirecting to the location. Reference - https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/assign-message-policy#copy

Comment: I figured it out. it was a silly mistake and I was not thinking from that prespective and that led to total ignorence of this. the path value between step 3 and step 4 were different and that was causing the cookies to not set and step 4 was being treated as new request everytime.